# Can I use the same itemprop twice in a page?

Tags: html, microformats

I'm trying to use microformat in my website so Google shows it like I want.

I have this simplified structure :

```
<h1>Name</h1>
<h2>Ocupation</h2>
<h4>Posted date</h4>
<div>Content<div>
```

I want both Ocupation and Content to appear in my description on Google. Is it ok if I add `itemprop="description"` to both elements? Will Google index both the ocupation and the content, or will it index only the Ocupation?

Comment: I guess you are talking about [tag:microdata], not [tag:microformats]?

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-to-one setup with this type of microformat. You need to merge the two items if you want them both in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

And try running your page. It will tell you if it is currently accepted